# Json Newtonsoft ignore any enumerable?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am creating a web api pushing out raw entities from EF. Can I turn off serialization of the collections relating to other tables, as to reduce potential data sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `JsonIgnore` attribute to properties you don't want to be serialized.

```
  [JsonIgnore]
  public IList<SomeObject> SomeCollection { get; set; }
```

Check this link: [Efficient JSON with Json.NET – Reducing Serialized JSON Size](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size)

Comment: Can I do this all collections, rather than tagging? I ask because I am using model first to generate the entities, so adding this attribute would be done by editing my t4 template otherwise.

Comment: Nevermind I see from the link that I can do this using a ContractResolver. Thanks!